# bot.remove_command('help') AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'remove_command'

Tags: python, discord, attributeerror, traceback

When I try to remove the default help command in replit it gives me this error:

```
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    bot.remove_command('help')
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'remove_command'
```

What do I have to do to remove the default help command on replit?

Comment: Clients have no concept of commands, Bots do.

Answer (score 0):

You are making your bot as a `Client` object. `remove_command` and commands in general are the functionality of `commands.Bot`. The documentation can be found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#bots)